# Fetching Data using Vlookup from multiple sheets

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

i have been trying to make a Dashboard in excel sheet which summarize the info present in the other two sheets.
[image: Dashboard]

first sheet contains list of drivers and few columns for extra details like Driver's unique ID, Driving license number, License Expiry and Vehicle Number he is driving.

[image: Driver List]

Second sheet contains list of vehicles and few other columns for extra details like car type, model year, Manufacturing company, and lastly the driver's unique id

[image]

I want to retrieve Driver and Vehicle Details on input of either Driver's ID no or Vehicle's Plate no.

it would be nice if answered using non-VBA/formula technique.

note: i cant put both info on 1 sheet because i have more columns than specified here, hence it difficult to maintain in 1 sheet.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can look up based on ID or Plate number both on the same cell.

You need to either pick one or determine which one you are looking up.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I4cNUT7fzPBgKpy4OO4dB0sgNBYOUA3Sgxnn-LaTl80), I made 3 look up so you can choose which one you prefer.

Preview (white cell = input cell, gray cell = formula cell):
[image: SS]

Comment: Thank you for your time,  3rd look up by ? might be useful for the job.i will mark yours as answer after implementation.